# Windows PE and the Boot.wim injecting

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, windows-server-2008, windows

Running Windows PE on 2008 server edition with WDS as the deploy point. Need to capture a Image but need to inject Intel® 82579LM and 82579V Gigabit Network drivers. The network driver is instead of being a '.inf' its a '.sys.'

**I attempt to try the .sys and inject it but this is what happens:**

> peimg /inf=c:\e1c6032.inf*.inf c:\Mount
>   Preinstallation Environment Image Setup Tool for Windows
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

**PEIMG failed to complete the operation with status code 0x80070003**.

I really need some help here because looking all over for the INF on the system with no luck since its all .sys files...

Is there anyway to inject .sys driver files into a boot.wim so we can PXE and then capture a image to deploy?

Comment: Windows PE doesn't "run" on 2008. WinPE is an Operating System. `dism` is usually used for injecting drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The .sys file is the actual driver; but you need the .inf file to tell Windows how to use the driver. Basically you need both. Download the correct drier from Intel, it will included the relevant inf files.